# How do I add dots in TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to add dots that would fill the space from section/subsection name to the page number in TOC. How do I do that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try the [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf) package with something like

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```

in case you're using the `article` class (See the package documentation for other classes).

As an illustration, let's try it with the `sample2e.tex` file; following `pdflatex sample2e` (two times), we got

[image]

Comment: `\cftchapleader` is undefined.

Comment: @an_ant Sorry, fixed it with `\cftsecleader`.

Comment: It doesn't do it.

Comment: @an_ant It works for me :( I added instructions on how I did it.

Comment: I'm sorry. It did the job! I knew it was `tocloft` but just wasn't able to search for it know. Thanks!

Comment: What to do for the `book` class?

Answer (score 5):

One way of doing this is to use the [memoir](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir?lang=en) class, where this is the default behaviour.

Memoir incorporates an extensive set of functions borged from other useful packages; I use it as my day-to-day general-purpose style for almost everything except presentations.

Comment: I would prefer to stick with article for now, if this is possible. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: You're welcome. Memoir is a bit daunting at first, but once you've taken the plunge, you've got more-or-less everything you'll commonly need *in one manual*.

Comment: @Saphar Koshet Thank you for correcting this. My original intenion (now destroyed by linkrot) was to go directly to the PDF manual, but the new URL looks a lot less brittle, so I'm happy to leave it as you have corrected.

Comment: Thanks for the note. "Whole" page or just the manual was an internal debate, and those who find your work on this will benefit from this added discussion. Good idea. Link to 2018 Dec 12 [manual](http://ctan.forsale.plus/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf).