# Customize TOC (page numbers) of classicthesis

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, classicthesis

I am using [classicthesis](http://code.google.com/p/classicthesis/) as a template for a study report. I would like to **customize the table of contents**. Here is a screen shot of another TOC that looks like what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: Table of contents example]

I prefer to have the **page numbers on the right side** and **dots inbetween**, like in the screen shot of the TOC. - I found the definition of the *classicthesis* style in `FrontBackmatter/Contents.tex`. However, I cannot see how to customize it?!

```
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{tableofcontents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % <-- 2 includes up to subsections in the ToC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % <-- 3 numbers up to subsubsections
\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}
\tableofcontents
\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `dottedtoc` to the options when calling `classicthesis`:

```
\usepackage[...,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
```

where `...` stands for the present options you're using.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you egreg. For everybody else: I added the parameter to `\documentclass[..., dottedtoc, ...]`.

Comment: @JJD I added the option to `documentclass`. Now the page numbers are aligned right like I want them to! But there are still no dots in between, even if I try http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7352/1660

Comment: @wrongusername I may depend on the version of `classicthesis` you are using. I saw that the `CHANGES` file has some notes about using the option `dottedtoc`. Please check this. I used version 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

For Classicthesis version 4.6, change `dottedtoc=false` to `true` in `\PassOptionsToPackage{...}{classicthesis}` in the classicthesis-config.tex file, where the `...` represents the current options passed.